# Turning translucency off on navigation bar missalignes views

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I have created layout with navigation bar and I have turned navigation bar translucent to no. I have added this code:

```
var overlay : UIView? // This should be a class variable

overlay = UIView(frame: view.frame)
overlay!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
overlay!.alpha = 0.8

view.addSubview(overlay!)
```

if I understand it correctly this should create overlay over my view. But it gives me result of this:
[image]
So I think that this missalignes my view. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its is happening because view origin changes if you set translucent
>   off. So Instead of using `view.frame` use `view.bounds`.

```
var overlay : UIView?

overlay = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
overlay!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
overlay!.alpha = 0.8

view.addSubview(overlay!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as below.

```
overlay = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
overlay!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
overlay!.alpha = 0.8

view.addSubview(overlay!)
```

Reason to use bounds instead of frame is,
you have turned of translucency. So your view will start from (0,64) instead of (0,0);

thats why its getting y=64 in frame value,
you can set y=0 or directly use view.bounds, in bounds it will give(x,y) = (0,0) and height and width as same as view.